# Uniform Convergence in baby Rudin -- less than or equal to $\varepsilon$

Tags: real-analysis

A few other lecture notes that I checked online all state the definition of uniform convergence as
\begin{equation}
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon.$$
\end{equation}
I wonder why Rudin chooses to write as 
\begin{equation}
$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon.$$
\end{equation}
Are there any significance of the "$\leq$" sign?

Comment: It really doesn't if everything else works.

Comment: Mentioned below, there is no (major) significance. Recall the (binary) relation "$\leq$" on some, fixed set means, obviously, "less than $or$ equal to." Recall the "$disjunctive$" operator in an exclusive sense, underlying the "$\leq$" relation here (e.g., recall the Trichotomy property of $\mathbb{R}$). So, if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ and $a<b$, then $a\leq b$ is true (the equality part is tacked on). Lastly, if equality does hold above, all that means we've found an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n\geq N$, and all $x\in E$ we have $f_{n}(x)=f(x)$ after letting $\varepsilon\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: I also wanted to say that this post is helpful - - thank you for your query. In several other analysis texts, I've always seen the strict inequality in the definition of uniform convergence of a sequence of functions. I'm rigorously working through Baby Rudin (w/ aspiration to work through Rudin's Green book immediately afterwards), and the non-strict inequality in Rudin's definition is the first time I've seen it presented this way, to which I found this post for verification. I'm not sure if there is another text with a similar definition, but thank you for asking.

Answer (score 3):

No the fact that (1) for every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|a_n|<c$ is equivalent to

(2) for every $c>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|a_n|\leq c$.

(1) implies (2) it is easy.

and if (2) is true, replace $c$ by $c/2$ for  $c/2>0$, there exists $N$ such that $n>N$ implies that $|a_n|\leq c/2<c$.

Answer (score 0):

In (almost?) all definitions of convergence it is possible to use either $\le$ or $<$, leading to equivalent notions. You don't have to stick to one or another.

If I had to choose, I would say the first form is most practical because we have often to use limits to prove these inequalities, and in that case all $<$ "become" $\le$. For instance, if you show:

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \forall \delta>0, |f_n(x)| < 12\delta+\epsilon$$

Then ($\delta \to 0$) gives $|f_n(x)| \le \epsilon$, although you had strict inequalities at the beginning.